# Uncaught ReferenceError: __VUE_HMR_RUNTIME__ is not defined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to add vue.js to a project with webpack, when I run I get an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: **VUE_HMR_RUNTIME** is not defined' in console.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h3>{{text}}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
    data(){
      return {
          text: 'Welcome'
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.common';
import App from "./App.vue";

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

vue-loader installed

Answer (score 0):

just update your vue-loader. in recent weeks, it updates fast! from v16 back to v15.